# The url automatically prepends symbol ? when using $.ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, yii, yii2

I am having some issues when using `$.ajax()` with Yii2. The url automatically prepends `?` symbol just before the parameters / data.

The code is given below:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl; ?>/room/BillPayment',
    data: DATA,
    traditional: true,
    success: function (data) {
```

Now my url becomes: `http://localhost/testdata/room/billpayment?` followed by params. But the end result is it gives error as **Bad request**.

So how do I remove the `?` symbol?

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct syntax for passing params in a **Query String**, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string for more information.

So, if you don't want the `?`, don't pass params, but build your own full URL instead.

Answer (score 0):

It's completely normal if request type is `GET`.

The common reasons of `Bad Request`:

**1)** Required controller action parameters are missing.

**2)** Wrong request type (for example `GET` instead of `POST`), usually it happens with attached `VerbFilter`.

**3)** Missed CSRF token. Usually it happens when using AngularJs for example.

You can change request type to `POST`, but it's recommended if you are modifying something, for getting data using `GET` is completely OK.